# change of order in a double series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Sorry for this simple question, but I never learned nothing about double sums )= , I only know what they are . But finally I had a problem where I need to know something about this, wondering if anyone has material to learn the basics, such as the product of summations, I can write as a double sum and vice versa, learn to turn the indices, etc. Order to gain a little more fluent in basic properties of these sums, and not have to always be deducting things that everybody knows) =
Not only with double of multiple sums , also with multiple series, But Only something basic to learn the typical properties )= only this. Thanks!

Comment: Iverson brackets can be a great aid when changing summation order for multiple series.

Comment: So, have you found my answer helpful? Is there some way in which it is lacking? Speak up - no one can help you if you maintain silence.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.statpower.net/Content/SubscriptAndSummationNotation.pdf), starting around page 11, looks pretty good to me.